# How to change the language of SimpleSchema

Tags: internationalization, simple-schema

SimpleSchema allows for overwriting the default error messages for all schema defined after the following call:

```
SimpleSchema.setDefaultMessages({
  messages: {
    'en': {
      required: '{{{label}}} is required'
    }
  }
})
```

Very nice, now I want to add a bunch of languages, which is simple enough with the message object, but I cannot figure out how to change the language SimpleSchema uses.

Internally SimpleSchema uses the MessageBox class per schema instance. But MessageBox instances are not available globally before defining schemas and I cannot find anything in the SimpleSchema package readme code enabling to set or change the language.

How do I define or change the global language SimpleSchema uses to determine which messages to use?

Comment: Have you checked [gwendall:simple-schema-i18n package?](https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-simple-schema-i18n)

Comment: Yes, I looked at it, but it is not a real option right now because it is longer being maintained, and is based on tap:i18n, which is stale with outdated dependencies.